# Getting the boolean value of a CheckBox cell in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, checkbox, casting, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that has a `Checkbox` in every first cell of a row. I want to loop through my `DataGrid` rows and get the rows if the `Checkbox` in that cell is checked.

This is my code in checking the `DataGrid`:

**Edited based on Ilan's answer**:

```
Private Sub ApproveBtn_Clicked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)


    For i As Integer = 0 To TimeSheetAppDGrid.Items.Count - 1

        TimeSheetAppDGrid.SelectedItem = TimeSheetAppDGrid.Items(i)
        Dim row As Row = DirectCast(TimeSheetAppDGrid.SelectedItems(0), Row)

        Dim mycheckbox = TryCast(TimeSheetAppDGrid.Columns(0).GetCellContent(TimeSheetAppDGrid.Items(i)), ContentPresenter)
        If mycheckbox Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
        Dim checkBox = GetAllVisualChildren(mycheckbox).OfType(Of CheckBox)().FirstOrDefault(Function(box) box.Name = "chkSelectAll")
        If checkBox Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim isChecked = checkBox.Checked

        If isChecked = True Then

            MsgBox(row.Mark)

        End If

    Next


End Sub
```

The code below doesn't seem to be accepted by VB.NET causing the compilation error that says "`Value of type 'FrameworkElement' cannot be converted to 'CheckBox'.`" After searching the web, almost all of the answers have this code in it but in C# so I converted it:

```
Dim mycheckbox As CheckBox = TryCast(TimeSheetAppDGrid.Columns(0).GetCellContent(TimeSheetAppDGrid.SelectedItems(0)), CheckBox)
```

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/848229/how-to-get-cell-Id-No-value-of-selected-datagrid-r) is where I got the code. Below is the original line of code from C#:

```
CheckBox mycheckbox = myGrid.Columns[5].GetCellContent(myGrid.Items[i]) as CheckBox;
```

This is my xaml for the DataGrid:

```xaml
<DataGrid Name ="TimeSheetAppDGrid" Margin="16,200,48,0"  CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 8 8 8" materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8"  IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single"  >

    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridRow}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_DoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <CheckBox Name="AllChkBox" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="chkSelectAll" Margin="3.5 0 0 0"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=AllChkBox,
                                  Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate> 
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Mark}" Header="Mark" Width="120" MaxWidth="120"
         EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnEditingStyle}"/>
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProjectCode}" Header="Project Code" Width="130" MaxWidth="130"
         EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"/>
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Project}" Header="Project" Width="250" MaxWidth="250"
         EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"/>
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PM}" Header="Project Manager" Width="230" MaxWidth="230"
         EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"/>
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Activity}" Header="Activity" Width="600" MaxWidth="600"
         EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"/>
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Today}" Header="Date" Width="200" MaxWidth="200"
         EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"/>
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Regular}" Header="Regular" Width="130" MaxWidth="130"
         EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"/>
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Overtime}" Header="Overtime" Width="130" MaxWidth="130"                                            
         EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "The code below doesn't seem to be accepted by VB.NET". What does that actually mean? If there's a compilation error then say that and provide the error message. That way, we know what we're looking for. Perhaps you could also provide the original C# code so that those of us who know both languages can see what issues there may be with your translation.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention its a compilation error. The error says: Value of type 'FrameworkElement' cannot be converted to 'CheckBox'.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this ? You're already using data binding for your checkbox IsChecked property are you not, so you can get at that information through simpler means.

Comment: @auburg The IsChecked is binded to the AllChkBox, so when I check the AllChkBox, all the checkboxes in the datagrid are checked and vice versa once unchecked. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't use WPF much so I'm no expert but I'm looking at the documentation for the `DataGrid` class and I notice that the `Items` property, which the original C# code used, and the `SelectedItems` property, which your VB code uses, are inherited from different base classes and are different types.  It would not be surprising to learn that getting an item from each of them would return objects of different types, which would explain why the C# cast works and the VB one doesn't.

Comment: @Kreyah Dear Kreyah you have two different positions of a check box. One of the positions is inside each cell(the name of each checkbox is chkSelectAll) and another position is inside the column header(there is only one, named AllChkBox). In my current code the relation is to the checkbox(named chkSelectAll) that is inside a specific cell, but as I can understand you search the AllChkBox. That is the reason that you can't find anything!!! There is no any check box with this name there!!!

Comment: @Ilan Sorry if you're having a hard time with me. But the GetAllVisualChildren() is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. I added the VisualTreeHelperExtensions class in my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take look at the visual tree generated using `Snoop`, so that your cast works properly.

Simplest approach is to keep updating a `Dictionary<int, DataGridRow>` upon `Checked/Unchecked` events of the `CheckBox`.

Sorry the code is in C#.

XAML :

```
<CheckBox Name="AllChkBox" Checked="AllChkBox_Checked" Unchecked="AllChkBox_Unchecked" />

<CheckBox Name="chkSelectAll" Margin="3.5 0 0 0" 
          Checked="chkSelectAll_Checked" Unchecked="chkSelectAll_Unchecked" 
          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=AllChkBox, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Code :

```
    Dictionary<int, DataGridRow> rows = new Dictionary<int, DataGridRow>();

    private void chkSelectAll_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cur_item = DGrid.CurrentItem;
        int cur_index = DGrid.Items.IndexOf(cur_item);

        if (cur_index == -1) // header checkbox is checked
            return;

        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cur_item);
        rows.Add(DGrid.Items.IndexOf(cur_item), row);            
    }

    private void chkSelectAll_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cur_item = DGrid.CurrentItem;
        rows.Remove(DGrid.Items.IndexOf(cur_item));
    }

    private void AllChkBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in DGrid.Items)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            rows.Add(DGrid.Items.IndexOf(item), row);
        }
    }

    private void AllChkBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rows.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: I edited your code so that errors are not presents. It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion there is some conceptual error in your adopted solution:

> CheckBox mycheckbox = myGrid.Columns[5].GetCellContent(myGrid.Items[i]) as CheckBox;

I've checked it and when we use the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`, like in your case, the value that is accepted(mycheckbox) is the ContentPresenter because there is the DataTemplate behind the cell(because you are using the DataTemplate). That is why the code is actually isn't working.

The solution that I'm suggesting you is to get the check box object from the ContentPresenter(the code is in C# you will have to convert it to VB), since it is the ContentPresenter's visual child(you can se this in [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)).

**UpdateHere is the GetAllVisualChildren code:**

```
public static class VisualTreeHelperExtensions
{
    public static T FindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //get parent item
            DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

            //we've reached the end of the tree
            if (parentObject == null) return null;

            //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
            T parent = parentObject as T;
            if (parent != null)
                return parent;
            child = parentObject;
        }
    }

    public static List<DependencyObject> GetAllVisualChildren(this DependencyObject parent)
    {
        var resultedList = new List<DependencyObject>();
        var visualQueue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
        visualQueue.Enqueue(parent);

        do
        {
            var depObj = visualQueue.Dequeue();
            var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj);

            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var v = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                visualQueue.Enqueue(v);
            }

            resultedList.Add(depObj);
        } while (visualQueue.Count > 0);

        resultedList.RemoveAt(0);
        return resultedList;
    }

}
```

**Do next things in order to import the VisualTreeHelperExtensions class to VB**

1. Create a C# class library as the part of your solution.
2. Add the VisualTreeHelperExtensions class into a new created project.
3. Compile your C# class library.
4. Add the new create(and compiled) class library into your vb.net project as a reference(dll).

**Update #3 - changed vb code**

```
Dim mycheckbox = TryCast(TimeSheetAppDGrid.Columns(0).GetCellContent(TimeSheetAppDGrid.Items(0)), ContentPresenter)
    If mycheckbox Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim checkBox = mycheckbox.GetAllVisualChildren().OfType(Of CheckBox)().FirstOrDefault(Function(box) box.Name = "chkSelectAll")
    If checkBox Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim isChecked = checkBox.IsChecked

    If isChecked = True Then

        MsgBox("Checked")

    End If
```

**VB.net CheckBox example**

1. [CheckBox Control WPF In VB.NET.](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/checkbox-control-wpf-in-vb.net)
2. [CheckBox Class in .Net Framework(no any restriction to vb)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Since all that the .net CheckBox has its IsChecked boolean state presenter.

Regards.

Comment: How do I check if var children is checked?

Comment: I tried this : 
            Dim isChecked = checkBox.Checked

            If isChecked = True Then

                MsgBox(row.Mark)

            End If and it doesn't work

Comment: @Kreyah Did you get any exception? Turn on CLR exception, and in addition please check if there is any binding exception in your output window.

Comment: I don't get any exceptions and nothing displays in the Output window when I click the button.

Comment: @Kreyah I'm sorry but I can't understand, what did you can't do? what about the checkbox? did you get the checkbox now? Did it cast-ed well?

Comment: Each row in the datagrid has checkbox right. At the first cell. I tried checking some checkboxes to and get the current row and get a cell value if the checkbox is checked. I'll update my button click based on your code.

Comment: @Kreyah please can explain what is the question? what is the problem now? If I understand you well, you can get the checkbox now?

Comment: The first sentence of my main question. That is the question. How can I detect the state of the checkbox. The problem now is that the If statement whether the checkbox is checked is not working.

Comment: @Kreyah Dear Kreyah you have a small error. In my opinion you should define the next; Dim isChecked = checkBox.IsChecked, instead of your code(isChecked = checkBox.Checked), becaus the checkBox.Checked is the event. I've debugged your code with this change and it works well. Regards.

Comment: I cannot use the .IsChecked because IsChecked is not a member of checkBox.

Comment: I get two errors, 1st is Argument not specified for parameter 'parent' of 'Private Shared Function GetAllVisualChildren(parent As DependencyObject) As List(Of DependencyObject)'.

Comment: The second is : IsChecked because IsChecked is not a member of checkBox

Comment: @Kreyah So this mean that you import the GetAllVisualChildren incorrectly   . The result of this method is not a check box. Please see the updates in a few minutes.

Comment: How can I add a C# class library in a VB.net solution? I added the VisualTreeHelperExtensions in a class but the Dim checkBox = GetAllVisualChildren().OfType(Of CheckBox)().FirstOrDefault(Function(box) box.Name = "AllChkBox") still doesn't detect the function.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

ok, here's a more refined way of achieving what you need without having to search the visual tree looking for the checkbox (again in c# but hopefully shouldn't be difficult to translate). 
Firstly, i've created a Student class to bind to which implements INotifyPropertyChanged :

```
    public class Student:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isChecked;

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set { _isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
        public string Mark { get; set; }
        public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
        public string Project { get; set; }
        public string PM { get; set; }
        public string Activity { get; set; }
        public DateTime Today { get; set; }
        public string Regular { get; set; }
        public string Overtime { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I then add a row to my data grid with test data :

```
            TimeSheetAppDGrid.ItemsSource = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student { ProjectCode="Project1",Mark = "A",Today = DateTime.Today}
            };
```

In the XAML for the data template i've changed the binding to *not* bind to the header check box but bind to the student IsChecked property and i've added a clicked handler for AllChkBox checkbox in the header cell:

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <CheckBox Click="AllChkBox_OnClick" Name="AllChkBox" />
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  Name="chkSelectAll" Margin="3.5 0 0 0"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

For the AllChkBox clicked handler (AllChkBox_OnClick) i iterate through each data source (i.e. Student) and toggle the IsChecked property to the AllChkBox checked value:

```
        private void AllChkBox_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (var s in TimeSheetAppDGrid.ItemsSource)
            {
                Student st = s as Student;

                st.IsChecked = (bool) AllChkBox.IsChecked;
            }

        }
```

Now each item source (i.e. Student) can be interrogated for their IsChecked property (which is bound to the corresponding checkbox cell) without the need to fish around checking for the checkbox (excuse the pun) i.e.

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var source in TimeSheetAppDGrid.ItemsSource)
    {
        Student st = source as Student;

        if (st.IsChecked)
            MessageBox.Show("Is Checked");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't convert the if statement in the converters. I think the chk is only selecting the header of the column and not the first cell of each row.